# How do you go about solving the differential equation of the following form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$\frac{dy}{dt} + y(t) = k$, where $k$ is a constant.

Would the method of integrating factors typically used for the following forms work:

$\frac{dy}{dt} + a(t)y = b(t)$

Comment: Write $y'=k-a(t)$ and integrate – no need for fancy integrating factors here.

Comment: Oh wow. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would integrating factors have worked here?

Comment: @Rumi: No. Why should it work? What would it even *mean*? That method applies to a different type of ODE.

Comment: What I meant to ask was something different, I have made a slight edit. I have the following abstract form. $\frac{dy}{dt} + y(t) = k$, The goal is to solve for y(t) and get rid of dy/dt. Integrating factor method worked very cleanly as I had y(t) on one side and no dy/dt or y(t) on the other

Comment: In that case, the integrating factor method works. However, it is a bit easier to use separation of variables. One obtains
$$\int \frac{dy}{k-y}=\int dt.$$

Comment: @projectilemotion: I would say it's the other way around: integrating factors are much easier. With separation of variables, you have to treat the case $y=k$ separately, and also be careful with handling absolute value signs after integrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, integrating factors will work, here:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt}+y(t)&=k\\
e^{\int P(t)\,dt}&=e^t\\
e^t\,\frac{dy}{dt}+e^t\,y(t)&=k\,e^t\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^t\,y(t)\right]&=k\,e^t\\
e^t\,y(t)&=k\,e^t+C\\
y(t)&=k+C\,e^{-t}.
\end{align*}
To check, you plug back into the DE:
$$\dot{y}(t)=-Ce^{-t},$$
so that
$$\dot{y}(t)+y(t)=-Ce^{-t}+k+Ce^{-t}=k,$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can just integrate by passing everything except the derivative to the other side, i.e

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = k - a(t) \Rightarrow y = \int (k - a(t)) \ dt = kt - A(t) + C$$

where $A(t)$ is a primitive of $a(t)$ and $C$ is the integration constant.

Cheers!

Comment: It seems like the OP edited their question (replaced $a(t)$ with $y(t)$).

Comment: I did do that. Sorry about the confusion.